# Rendering a texture with OpenGL in Python is not

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I want to render a texture (using a .png) using the next code:

Everything goes well until I uncomment `object_cube.loadTextures()`

```py
# Execute with Python 3

import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

camera_x = 0
camera_z = 0
camera_y = 0
x = 0

Vertices = [
    [1, -1, 1],
    [-1, -1, 1],
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
]

class Ground:
    global camera_z

    def __init__(self):
        self.ground_vertices = (
            (-11, -2.01, 20),
            (11, -2.01, 20),
            (11, -2.01, -300),
            (-11, -2.01, -300)
        )

    def draw(self):
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, camera_z)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        for vertex in self.ground_vertices:
            glColor3fv((0, 0.5, 0.5))
            glVertex3fv(vertex)

        glEnd()
        glPopMatrix()


class Cube:
    def __init__(self, v=False):
        self.vertices = [
            [1, -1, 1],
            [-1, -1, 1],
            [-1, -1, -1],
            [1, -1, -1],
            [1, 1, -1],
            [-1, 1, -1],
            [-1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]
        ]
        self.surfaces = (
            (0, 1, 6, 7),
            (0, 1, 2, 3),
            (0, 3, 4, 7),
            (1, 2, 6, 5),
            (2, 3, 4, 5),
            (4, 5, 6, 7)
        )
        self.colors = (
            (105 / 255, 210 / 255, 231 / 255),
            (167 / 255, 219 / 255, 216 / 255),
            (224 / 255, 228 / 255, 204 / 255),
            (243 / 255, 134 / 255, 48 / 255)
        )
        self.colors2 = (
            (0.91, 0.31, 0.47),
            (0.84, 0.51, 0.54),
            (0.78, 0.64, 0.6),
            (0.78, 0.9, 0.85)
        )
        self.vertices_texture = (
            (0.0, 0.0),
            (1.0, 0.0),
            (1.0, 1.0),
            (0.0, 1.0),
        )
        self.v = v
        self.center = [0, 0, 0]

    def draw(self):
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        if not self.v:
            for surface in self.surfaces:
                x = 0
                for vertex in surface:
                    glColor3fv(self.colors2[x])
                    # glTexCoord2f(self.vertices_texture[x])
                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
                    x += 1
        else:
            for surface in self.surfaces:
                x = 0
                for vertex in surface:
                    glColor3fv(self.colors[x])
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.vertices_texture[x])
                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
                    x += 1

        glEnd()


    def set_vertices(self, max_distance, min_distance=-40):
        x_value_change = random.randrange(-10, 10)
        y_value_change = -1
        z_value_change = random.randrange(-1 * max_distance, min_distance)
        new_vertices = []
        for vertex in Vertices:
            new_vertex = []

            new_x = vertex[0] + x_value_change
            new_y = vertex[1] + y_value_change
            new_z = vertex[2] + z_value_change

            new_vertex.append(new_x)
            new_vertex.append(new_y)
            new_vertex.append(new_z)

            new_vertices.append(new_vertex)
        self.vertices = new_vertices
        self.center = [
            (self.vertices[2][0]+self.vertices[7][0])/2,
            (self.vertices[2][1]+self.vertices[7][1])/2,
            (self.vertices[2][2]+self.vertices[7][2])/2
        ]

    def rotate(self):
        glPushMatrix()
        glRotatef(25, 1, 0, 0)
        glPopMatrix()

    def loadTexture(self):
        textureSurface = pygame.image.load('./textures/ursa.png')
        textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureSurface, "RGBA", 1)
        width = textureSurface.get_width()
        height = textureSurface.get_height()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        texid = glGenTextures(1)

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        # return texid


def movInverse(event):
    global x
    y = 0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if(math.fabs(x) < 11):
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 1
        else:
            if(x < 0):
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 1
            else:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y += 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y -= 1

    glTranslatef(0, y, 0)


def leave(event):
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
        pygame.quit()
        quit()


def main():
    global camera_x, camera_y, camera_z, x
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL | OPENGLBLIT)
    max_distance = 300
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, max_distance)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glTranslatef(0, -10 / 2.4, -50)

    ground = Ground()

    cube = Cube(True)

    # cube.loadTexture()
    # I want to render the texture here, but when I do it, everything get screwed.
    my_cubes = []

    for i in range(50):
        tmp_cube = Cube()
        # tmp_cube.loadTexture()
        # I also tried to render it here, but I got the same result
        tmp_cube.set_vertices(max_distance)
        my_cubes.append(tmp_cube)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            leave(event)
            movInverse(event)

        M = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
        # print(M)
        camera_x = M[3][0]
        camera_y = M[3][1]
        camera_z = M[3][2]

        glTranslatef(0, 0, 1.5)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        ground.draw()

        glPushMatrix()
        if(math.fabs(x) < 11):  
            glTranslatef(x, -1.5, camera_z-20)

        glScalef(1 / 2, 1 / 2, 0)
        cube.draw()
        glPopMatrix()
        for tmp_cube in my_cubes:
            tmp_cube.draw()
            tmp_cube.center[2] += camera_z
            print(tmp_cube.center)

        for tmp_cube in my_cubes:
            if camera_z <= tmp_cube.vertices[0][2]:
                new_max = int(-1 * (camera_z - max_distance * 2))
                tmp_cube.set_vertices(new_max, int(camera_z - max_distance))

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main problem I got is that I get a little cube with the rendered image, but the rest is black. I don't know what happens with the rest of the elements it should draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).
This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color before you render the textured objects:

```cpp
glColor3f(1, 1, 1)
```

Two-dimensional texturing is enabled by [`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and can be disabled by `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.
If texturing is enables then the texture wich is currently bound when the geometry is drawn by the [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence is applied.

If you've want to draw objects which are textured, and other objects which are not, then you've to enable texturing before the object is drawn and to disable it after:

```py
class Cube:

    # [...]

    def draw(self):

        if self.v:
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1)

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        if not self.v:
            for surface in self.surfaces:
                for x, vertex in enumerate(surface):
                    glColor3fv(self.colors2[x])
                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        else:
            for surface in self.surfaces:
                for x, vertex in enumerate(surface):
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.vertices_texture[x])
                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()

        if self.v:
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

Comment: Hi. The solution you proposed worked, and I'm thankful for that, but I have another question, how could I render more than one texture? That is, once the last texture is loaded, it overlaps the other "loaded" above.
I load a new "texture" in a different object, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AnthonyLuzquiños All you've to do is to bind the proper texture object before drawing the quad (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)`). If you've more than 1 texture, then you've to create 1 texture object for each texture (e.g. `texid1`,  `texid2`, ...)